# Deploy Nuxt.js SPA to IIS

Tags: vue.js, iis, nuxt.js

I have a simple project using Nuxt.js building in SPA mode.

The official documentation says that you simply need to put the content of the `.nuxt/dist` folder after a `npm run build` to the root of your hosting dir.

Here is what the `npm run build` generates for me:

```
.nuxt/dist/
┣ client/
┃ ┣ 3cf8385bf6a4566ef93b.js
┃ ┣ 7c79864121ddfa160949.js
┃ ┣ b70349e040bca7777d93.js
┃ ┣ edc78b0c0850b91edb72.js
┃ ┣ f537e3bf431bc43e1b91.js
┃ ┗ LICENSES
┗ server/
┃ ┣ client.manifest.json
┃ ┗ index.spa.html
```

When I deploy this to an IIS 8.5 server, I get an error whenever I try to access the website (probably because I'm missing a `web.config` file or simply because IIS doesn't know how to serve this kind of app?).

How can I make this work?

I'm using nuxt@2.11.0

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating application you just need to run below command to build the app:

```
npm run build
```

it will create the dist folder inside of your application. point that folder in iis as a site folder path.

[image]

[image]

[image]

No need to move any folder or file anywhere.

root folder structure:

[image]

dist folder structure:

[image]

iis site detail:

[image]

make sure you assign the iis_iusrs and iusr full control permission to the site root folder.

[image]

below is the output:

[image]